$\operatorname{null}T = X$ and $\operatorname{range}T = Y.$
Here is the question I am thinking about:
Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional, $X$ is a subspace of $V,$ and $Y$ is a finite-dimensional subspace of $W.$ Prove that there exists $T \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$ such that $\operatorname{null}T = X$ and $\operatorname{range}T = Y$ if and only if $\operatorname{dim} X + \operatorname{dim} Y = \operatorname{dim} V.$
The forward direction follows from the rank nullity theorem, but what about the reverse direction?
Here are my thoughts:
Suppose that $\operatorname{dim} X + \operatorname{dim} Y = \operatorname{dim} V,$ we want to show that there exists $T \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$ such that $\operatorname{null}T = X$ and $\operatorname{range}T = Y.$
Let $x_1, \dots ,x_n$ be a basis of $X$ and $y_1, \dots ,y_m$ be a basis of $Y.$ Then $x_1, \dots ,x_n$ can be extended to a basis of $V,$ say,$x_1, \dots ,x_n, u_1, \dots ,u_m.$ Define $T \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$ as follows: $$T(a_1x_1 + \dots + a_nx_n + b_1u_1 + \dots + b_m u_m) = b_1y_1 + \dots + b_my_m.$$
But then I do not know how to show that $\operatorname{null}T = X$ and $\operatorname{range}T = Y.$ Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Edit:
I can use the following result without proof:
Suppose that $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional and that $U$ is a subspace of $V$. Prove that there exists $T\in\mathfrak{L}(V,W)$ such that $\text{null}(T)=U$ if and only if $\text{dim}(U)\geq\text{dim}(V)-\text{dim}(W)$.

You didn't finish defining $T$. This works: $$T(a_1x_1 + \dots + a_nx_n + b_1u_1 + \dots + b_m u_m)\=b_1y_1+b_2y_2+\ldots+b_m y_m
$$

oh sorry, yes I meant to define it like this, but then what? I can not see the big picture, why I finished? @Nothingspecial

Define $T(x_j)=0$, $T(u_j)=y_j$, extend by linearity.

@Emptymind Now, it should be clear by definition that $\text{range }T\subseteq Y$ and $\text{null }T\supseteq X$.

but I  want an equality not just a subset @Nothingspecial

@Emptymind Yes, that's the first step, try to prove the reverse inclusions to get the equality. Take a $y\in Y$, what does it look like? $y=\alpha_1y_1+\ldots+\alpha_my_m$ for some scalars $\alpha_i$. Now, $T(\alpha_1u_1+\ldots+\alpha_mu_m)=y$. Thus, $Y\subseteq \text{range }T$.

Suppose $Tv=0$ for some $v\in V$, write out $v$ in term of its coordinates. Realise that the coefficients of $y_i$'s must be zero and thus $v\in X$. That's it, you're done with $\text{null }T\subseteq X$. Have you learned about direct sum and/or complementary subspace? If so, then I'll post a more convenient answer.

I will edit my question with a result that I am allowed to use without proof @Nothingspecial

By construction $X\subseteq \ker T$ and $T(U)=Y\subseteq \text{image }T$ so $n \leq \dim \ker T$ and $m\leq \dim \text{ image }T$ but $\dim V = n + m \leq \dim \ker T + \dim \text{ image }T=\dim V$ tells you they are both met with equality so $X =\ker T$ and $Y=\text{ image }T$

You've defined $T \in \mathcal{L}(V, W)$ by
$$
T(a_1x_1 + \dots + a_nx_n + b_1u_1 + \dots + b_m u_m) = b_1y_1 + \dots + b_my_m
$$
But observe this is the same as having
\begin{cases}
&T(a_1x_1 + \dots + a_nx_n) = 0 \\
&T(b_1u_1 + \dots + b_m u_m) = b_1y_1 + \dots + b_my_m
\end{cases}
Then it's easy to see that $\text{null} \ T = \text{span}(x_1,\ldots,x_n),$ but we know that $X = \text{span}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. Hence, $\text{null} \ T = X$.
Also, we see that $\text{range} \ T = \text{span}(y_1,\ldots,y_m)$, but we know that $Y = \text{span}(y_1,\ldots,y_m)$. Hence, $\text{range} \ T = Y$.
